# fixed input text file to new xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I do have a text input which is of fixed length

```
abc01223jan20212605 mytext
```

I would want the output xml as

```
<bookings>
  <name>abc</name>
  <uid>o12</uid>
  <Date>23jan2021</date>
   <seq>2605</seq>
   <commnent>mytext</comment> 
  
</bookings>
```

I am unable to create an XSL with my defined tag names as I don't have an XSD to refer and also I couldn't refer those from my locals for my coding. These strings will be in the same position and I could take the values as substrings. But it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "no" media-type = "text/plain"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
            <xs:element name="Code">
                <xs:value-of> ABC01 </xs:value-of>
            </xs:element>       
 

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Even this didn't work. Not sure on the error

Comment: What is the source of the fixed length text input?

Comment: Here it would be initialised at the start of the XSL

Comment: If XSLT is suitable for processing XML structured documents, I think it is better to use another tool to change an unparsed text into XML, even if XSLT 3.0 is able to do that.

Comment: *"it would be initialised at the start of the XSL"* That doesn't mean anything. The question is how do you pass the string to the XSL transformation. Once you have the string, parsing it is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing a fixed-length string into elements is trivial. Consider the following example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="input">abc01223jan20212605mytext</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <bookings>
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 1, 3)"/>
        </name>
        <uid>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 4, 3)"/>
        </uid>
        <date>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 7, 9)"/>
        </date>
        <seq>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 16, 4)"/>
        </seq>
        <comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 20)"/>
        </comment> 
    </bookings>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using any XML as the (dummy) input, this will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookings>
  <name>abc</name>
  <uid>012</uid>
  <date>23jan2021</date>
  <seq>2605</seq>
  <comment>mytext</comment>
</bookings>
```

As I said in a comment, the only question is how do you pass the string to the XSL transformation. If you can pass it as a parameter, then this is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

AWK is a good tool for creating the XML file you want:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = " 3 3 9 4 1 999 "; print "<bookings>" }
        { 
          print "  <name>" $1 "</name>"
          print "  <uid>" $2 "</uid>" 
          print "  <date>" $3 "</date>"
          print "  <seq>" $4 "</seq>" # $5 contains always one useless space
          print "  <comment>" $6 "</comment>"
        }
  END   { print "</bookings>" }
' lines.txt
```